# Algolia: Fetch records where both facet conditions are satisfied

Tags: algolia, react-instantsearch

An example data structure of my record(s) are:

```
{
    foo: "bar",
    foo1: [
        { b1: "x", b2: "y" }
    ]
}
```

I am using React InstantSearch widgets where I have many refinement lists, two of which are on `foo1.b1` and `foo.b2` attributes.

**Expectation** - user selects value "x" for `foo1.b1` attribute and "y" for `foo1.b2` attribute. Records that have both values set should be returned. (AND condition).

**Actual**: Records where either `foo1.b1` is "x" OR `foo1.b2` is "y" are being returned.

Since I am using React InstantSearch widget and RefinementList, I am not sure how I can achieve the above. I looked at connectRefinmentList and virtual refinement lists but they seem to only work with a single attribute at a time.

Here's a [Demo link](https://www.algolia.com/interface-demos/d5e46deb-0c5f-4a77-867a-40510fc51b24?utm_medium=page_link&utm_source=dashboard) of the issue.

Select Language as `English` and Language Level as `Conversational`.

**Expected**: Only Item # 3 and Item # 4 to show up.

**Actual**: All 4 items are seen.

Comment: it is because 2 of the items have 2 elements in the array with 1 having x Conversational and the other y English. those 2 are getting matched

Comment: a solution is to duplicate the items so that each have a single foo1.x and foo1.y. downside is it creates reduncancies. and also you will have to group by title or something before rendering the hits

Comment: something similar caused due to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74381551/how-to-query-algolia-data-with-in-the-array-of-object

Comment: correction: from x and y i meant b1 and b2